# Dataframe .loc not appending rows as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running code in which I add rows to an existing dataframe. With the below code:

```
df_tmp = df_inputfile.iloc[5:8,np.asarray(indices)[0]]  # rows 5-7 include header information
#df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})
print(len(df_tmp.index))
# append a row with ticker name repeated
df_tmp.loc[len(df_tmp.index),:] = 'a'
print(len(df_tmp.index))
df_tmp.loc[len(df_tmp.index),:] = 'b'
# append a row with label that was used for match
print(len(df_tmp.index))
df_tmp.loc[len(df_tmp.index),:] = 'c' # does not work
print(len(df_tmp.index))
```

I would expect to see output 3, 4, 5, 6 but instead I see 3, 4, 5, 5. The 
`df_tmp.loc[len(df_tmp.index),:] = 'c'` line is not appending data! When I uncomment `df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})`, the code behaves as expected and prints 3,4,5,6.

What in inputfile dataframe could cause my attempt at appending to behave unexpectedly?? The inputfile dataframe is simply parsed from a CSV file.

Comment: df.iloc will pick first and last-1 ... in this case you have df.iloc[5:8] meaning it will only read rows 5,6,7, which if I am right, equates to row 3,4 and 5. There is no row 6, and as such your last append will still read 5. change the code to df.iloc[5:9] and see what you get.  df.loc[5:8] will read in 5,6,7,8. so u might want that instead.

Comment: I am confused. Why does the initial file read give indexes 3,4,5 rather than 0,1,2? I also tried df_tmp = df_tmp.append(df_inputfile.iloc[5:8,np.asarray(indices)[0]] with the same result.

Comment: cant say since you have access to the data. is there an index column in the csv file? you could have a look at that and see how it is numbered.

Comment: read_excel has indexing set to none by default.My code is df_inputfile = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None, sheet_name=sheet_name)

Comment: i have no idea where the 'error' is coming from.

Comment: index_col=None is default but I did try setting it manually. Still same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208014/discussion-between-sammywemmy-and-goldfinger).

Comment: If you want to append a row, why not just use [`DataFrame.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) ? In any case, repeatedly appending to a DataFrame is less than ideal, why do you need to do so?